# Computername and string search

Tags: string, powershell, search

Having some string trouble, I can get the computer name using `$env:computerName` and it returns something like `ABC1211`.  I am guessing that the `ABC1211` is an object and I want to do a search.  I want to search this for the characters `ABC` and then I need to do some other things with certs.  I am having problem searching for the `ABC`.

I tried:

```powershell
[string[]]$test = $env:computerName
```

to turn it into a string and then do a search within `$test` by:

```powershell
if ($test.contains(("DEF")) {
    Write-Host "Yeah" 
}
else {
    Write-Host "NO"
}
```

but its not working.  Am I missing something?  I am guessing this is really simple, but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out...was a lot more simple than I thought.  Here's the answer:  -match

I just had to use that instead of .contains or -like  also I don't need to change the object into a string.

Comment: `-match` uses Regex to search for a pattern.  You are only trying to search for static text however, which means it is not necessary (and somewhat inefficient).  `.contains` should work fine if you use it as I demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`$env:computerName` is already a string.  There is no need to cast it to `[string[]]`.  Just call the `.contains` method on the variable directly:

```powershell
if ($env:computerName.contains("ABC")) {
    Write-Host "Yeah" 
}
else {
    Write-Host "NO"
}
```

---

Incidentally, casting a variable to `[string[]]` makes an array of strings, not a single string:

```powershell
PS > [string[]]$test = $env:computerName     
PS > $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                 
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array             


PS >
```

So, `$test` was actually of the form `($env:computerName,)` and you were using `Array.Contains` instead of `String.Contains`.

To cast to a string, you would use just `[string]`:

```powershell
[string]$test = $env:computerName
```

But as I said above, this is unnecessary since `$env:computerName` is already a string.